# Which class/function is responsible for indexing of cataloginventory_stock?

Tags: magento2, indexing

As per [Magento's document](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/indexing.html#m2devgde-indexing-outofbox) , function responsible for indexing of `cataloginventory_stock` is `Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Indexer\Stock::execute($ids)`.

For debugging purpose, I have modified this function and added `var_dump($ids);exit;` at the top and ran command `php bin/magento indexer:reindex cataloginventory_stock` but my code wasn't fired and indexing was completed successfully.

Which class is actually responsible for the re-indexing of `cataloginventory_stock` ?

Comment: magento version?

Comment: Magento version is 2.3.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file is correct, but you are looking at wrong method try executeFull()